# Serve specifics request in dedicated server for same domain

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

Asp.net Core App in IIS with its own domain served in two balanced servers.

Is it possible to have a specific controller attended in a third server only, but under the same domain?

Let's say http://MyApp.com/MyBusyController served in the third server and the rest of the app in the other two?

The reason for this is that this controller will be doing some heavy operations and  it's going to get very busy, and don't want to degrade the other two servers, but have to be under the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ARR load balance instead.  So that URL rewrite rule can be used to manage the load balance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/http-load-balancing-using-application-request-routing

You can create default inbound ARR_loadbalance rule and exclude the request to MyBusyController:

```
  <rule name="ARR_MyWebFarm_loadbalance" enabled="false" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://MyWebFarm/{R:0}" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="MyBusyController" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
```

Then you can create reverse proxy rule for specific controller MyBusyController:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing